# Screen turn on without reason

Tags: android, screen, standby, powermanager

I'm trying to build a standBy like activity, and I'm near to my goal, the only issue that I found is that sometimes after I switch off the screen Android turn it on immediately and I can't understand why.

I have a terminal linked to a proprietary board, when I launch a specific activity I'm able to let the board send a message to my device to turn off the screen. The result is that the screen turn off, but only for a moment, because immediately Android turn on the screen.

Here is the log of my application

```
         I/ProprietaryStandbyActivity(31326): onCreate
         I/ProprietaryStandbyActivity(31326): terminalDisplayOff 192.168.0.123

         Sending UDP message to turn Off the screen
         D/WindowManager( 2147): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Not passing key to user.
         D/OpenGLRenderer(31326): Enabling debug mode 0
         I/ActivityManager( 2147): Displayed ProprietaryStandbyActivity: +208ms
         D/WindowManager( 2147): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Going to sleep.
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Not passing key to user.
         I/PowerManagerService( 2147): Going to sleep by user request...
         I/LQ      ( 2147):  ##########   Thread(StopWifi).start(    !!!!
         D/SurfaceFlinger( 1302): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0xb84ed450
         E/IMGSRV  ( 1302): :0: ####hwc_device_blank: disp:0 blank:1
         V/ProprietaryStandbyActivity(31326): Called onPause
         I/ProprietaryStandbyActivity(31326): onStop 
         D/PowerManagerService-JNI( 2147): Excessive delay in autosuspend_enable()  

         while turning screen off: 380ms

         D/UdpExecutor(30580): ###UDP  socket listening...

         D/WindowManager( 2147): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Waking up.
         D/SensorManager( 2147): >>>>>>> set discard sensrtime =3
         E/&&&&&&  ( 2147): /data/user/gsensor_data ----> not exists.
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Not passing key to user.
         D/SurfaceFlinger( 1302): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0xb84ed450
         E/IMGSRV  ( 1302): :0: ####hwc_device_blank: disp:0 blank:0
         I/PowerManagerService( 2147): Waking up from sleep...
         V/KeyguardServiceDelegate( 2147): onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = 

         com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$18@41da4ae0)
         V/KeyguardServiceDelegate( 2147): **** SHOWN CALLED ****
         I/WindowManager( 2147): No lock screen! windowToken=null
```

The strange log that I can't understand is this line

```
         D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Waking up.
```

It seems that somehow the InputManager class receive an input to wake up the screen, even if I give no input.
Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: You must debug your code to know the real reason. Maybe you are using a thread that it waked up after a sleeping period.

Comment: Obviously I debugged my code, but I have no instruction that turn on the screen. Are you suggesting that maybe some service can turn on the screen simply because is running in background? It would be a very strange behavior.

Comment: Maybe one of your services or threads is doing some stuff with *WindowManager* or *WakeLock* clases. This can cause the turning on of your screen. Its just a guess!

Answer (score 0):

D/InputManager-JNI( 2147): handleInterceptActions: Waking up.

this means an key or other events with policy flag "wake" is comming.